# Storing an std::thread in C++11 smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, shared-ptr, stdthread

In `C++ 11` & above **what are the advantages or disadvantages** when storing an `std::thread` as a member of class directly like so:

```
std::thread my_thread;
```

As opposed to storing a `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` to the thread like so:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::thread> my_thread_ptr;
```

Is any of the code options better than other? Or it doesn't matter, just 2 separate ways of handling the thread object.

Comment: Aren't the advantages or disadvantages kind of, you know, obvious? Look at what `thread`'s special member functions do, and then decide if that's the behavior you want form the outer class.

Comment: Why would you ever store it in an `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`? I don't see the point, the `std::thread` just wraps the implementation-defined thread handle.

Comment: This seems like a list question. Instead ask some specific question about a specific case and explain your constraints.

Comment: @NicolBolas I am not talking about forming an outer class. what I meant is - there is a class which needs the thread alive for fully within the lifetime of its object but not wrapping the thread. so the thread object is a member. Now my question is that "when the thread object is a class member, is there an advantage is storing it in a smart pointer". Not sure what you found so wrong about this simple question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

May be there is some less common reason for usage of pointer (or smart pointer) member but for common usages it seems that `std::thread` either does not apply or is sufficiently flexible itself:

- We may want more control over lifetime of object, for example to initialize it "lazily". The `std::thread` already supports it. It can be made in "not representing a thread" state, assigned real thread later when needed, and it has to be explicitly `join`ed or `detached`ed before destruction.
- We may want a member to be transferred to/from some other ownership. No need of pointer for that since `std::thread` already supports move and swap.
- We may want the object pointed at to be dynamically polymorphic. That does not apply since `std::thread` does not have any virtual member functions.
- We may want opaque pointer for to hide implementation details and reduce dependencies, but `std::thread` is standard library class so we can't make it opaque.
- We may want to have shared ownership. That is fragile scenario with `std::thread`. Multiple owners who can assign, swap, detach or join it (and there are no much other operations with thread) can cause complications.
- There is mandatory cleanup before destruction like `if (xthread.joinable()) xthread.join();` or `xthread.detach();`. That is also more robust and easier to read in destructor of owning class instead of code that instruments same thing into deleter of a smart pointer.

So unless there is some uncommon reason we should use thread as data member directly.

Comment: Shared ownership is really the only use case I can come up with right now

Answer (score 1):

If you have an option of having your std::thread as a member variable, go for it. If not, consider other options. Don't wrap it inside `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` unless you have a serious reason for doing so. Given that `std::thread` is movable by itself, it's pretty unlikely wrapping it into a smart pointer will be necessary.