# Can the thread object be deleted after std::thread::detach?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a question about `std::thread::detach()`. In [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/detach/) it says 'After a call to this function, the `thread` object becomes *non-joinable* and can be *destroyed* safely', by which it seems to mean that the destructor `~thread()` may be called safely.

My question is, does this mean that it is ok & safe to `delete` a thread object immediately after calling `detach()`, as in the following sample code? Will the function `my_function` continue safely, and safely use its `thread_local` variables and variables that are global to the program?

```
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

void my_function(int t)
{
        sleep(t);
}

int main()
{
        std::thread *X = new std::thread(my_function, 10);
        X->detach();
        delete X;

        sleep(30);

        return 0;
}
```

The code 'runs' ok, I just want to know if this is safe from the point of view of memory ownership. My motivation here is to have a program that runs 'forever', and spawns a few child threads from time to time (e.g. every 30 seconds.) Each child thread then does something, and dies: I do not want to have to somehow keep track of the children in the parent thread, call `join()` and *then* `delete`.

Comment: Yes. That's just another way of destroying the `thread` object.

Comment: Put some curly brackets around it, then it will work even without `new` and `delete`: `{ std::thread x(my_function, 10); x.detach(); } // end of scope will destroy x` ;-)

Comment: Deleteing is usually valid only with dynamically allocated objects but allocating std::thread dynamically does not make sense.

Comment: @ÖöTiib, How does it not make any sense?

Comment: @SolomonSlow because it is pointless pessimisation. The only semi-imaginable reason to have pointer of std::thread is shared ownership and even that is most likely bad architecture.

Comment: @ÖöTiib So, not the best choice maybe for most programmers. But there _are_ special cases. If it's smart to use pool threads, then somebody has to implement the pool. High-performing thread-pool implementations often are designed to kill-off excess worker threads when demand is low, and spool up new ones when demand is high. If you were implementing that, then you might well use dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: @SolomonSlow  The std::thread is already a class managing resource dynamically and adding another layer of dynamic management is over-engineering without benefits. On your example case the excess threads can be joined and later actual threads can be assigned to joined threads when need arises again. Having pointers just adds additional pointless delete after join and pointless new when need arises.

Comment: @ÖöTiib, Working with what's available is not "over engineering." It's more like the exact opposite of over-engineering. In the example that I cite, there is a genuine need to create and destroy OS threads on demand. If the threads are managed by `std::thread` instances (i.e., working with what's available), then how would that be possible except by calling `std::thread` constructors and destructor? And what better way is there to to do that in C++ besides using `new` and `delete`?

Comment: @SolomonSlow but maybe read documentations? Attempt to delete a std::thread that you have not joined with std::thread::join will cause your program to end with std::terminate.

Comment: @ÖöTiib, Calling `t->join();` before `delete t;` does not sound like a hard problem.

Comment: @SolomonSlow but my whole point was that calling new was pointless at first place and so is calling that delete after actual thread has been joined. IOW neither provided any benefits and so did not make sense.

Comment: Yes, and I showed one example where calling new was not pointless.

Comment: We are going in circles; I already explained how on case of your example the new and delete are as pointless.

Comment: I have explained the logic why pointers of std::thread are pointless more throughoutly in answer to that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832054/storing-an-stdthread-in-c11-smart-pointer/44835955#44835955 Feel free to provide your alternative answer there.